# Call reload of payment methods in OneStepCheckout for Magento?

Tags: javascript, magento

On page load geoip finds the country the customer is from, or atleast tries to, however if the country is changed the payment methods do not update. I use payment restrictions to set rules for which methods show for certain countries. If i select another country and then go back to the previous country the payment methods update and everything is fine.

Ajax update for country is of course enabled in onestepcheckout.

So to solve the issue I looked at the onestepcheckout js file which has the get_save_methods_function which seems to update the payment methods.

My issue is i'm not sure how to call this function on document load.

Is there another way i can trigger the update?

plugin website http://www.onestepcheckout.com/ and demo http://demo.onestepcheckout.com/

Thanks!

Comment: best way to find out is to write to support@onestepcheckout.com

Comment: I have not seen such support request there. So yes no luck if not reported.

Comment: Well i sent an email explaining the problem and got a reply explaining how to configure the extension which is not at all related. I sent a reply to try to explain my issue further and have received no reply from them.

Comment: I went ahead and changed to http://www.apptha.com/category/extension/Magento/OneStepCheckout It works for our magento install and seems to have no issues. I gave up on fixing this after a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the job of the shipping and payment modules to do all the needed checks.
het
If you are on Apache geoip you'll have $_SERVER with the country code in it. You can pull this up in your module(s) and see whether to return a rate or not.

Doing it in the shipping/payment modules will save a lot of effort and be easier to test than hacking OPC.

Comment: Well it all works, its just onestepcheckout that does not reload the payment methods for me. I have to manually deselect and select the country to make the update happen. So my question was how I could trigger this update on page load instead?

Comment: What happens if you save the quote object in the backend at every step?

Comment: payment methods get reloaded twice when triggered by country change or shipping change for example